# Use other payment methods when paying for Recurring Profiles

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, payment-gateway, recurring

I want to allow my customers to be able to pay for their nominal items (recurring profile/ subscription)using different payment methods. As of now, my store only uses PayPal for these kinds of transactions.

1.) How can I allow my users to pay for their nominal items using different payment methods? (Credit/Debit Card, Load, Bank Transfer, etc)

2.) If there is an extension for this, what is your recommendation?

Thank you for your response.
I am using Magento 1.9.2.3

How can I allow customers to have options on what payment method theycan use when paying for Recurring Profiles?

Answer (score 1):

You can develop your own extension:

http://www.blog.modulesgarden.com/recurring-payments-in-magento/

You have other modules:

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/subscriptions-and-recurring-payments-by-aheadworks.html

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/subscriptions-and-recurring-payments-1.html